# 185.3 + 12.37 = 197.67000000000002?

Tags: javascript, math, addition

This page has a simple alert:

```
alert(185.3 + 12.37);
```

To me, that should equal 197.67

However, in the browsers I've tested (Chrome/Safari on OSX, FF on Win7) the answer is:

197.67000000000002

Why is that? Is this just a known bug or is there more to JavaScript addition than I realize?

Comment: Welcome to the world of floats. See [Understanding floating point problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664662/understanding-floating-point-problems) for example.

Comment: Hey its floating point it's never exact.

Comment: Soooooooooooooooooooooooo many duplicates...

Comment: Those are numbers that don't have exact binary representations, so it's not at all unusual to get some noise in the low-order bits.

Comment: @Mike...ah! Thanks for that. So it's an issue of our base10 math converting to binary.

Comment: @Richard: Actually, floating point is exact, I believe, if you stick to integers, or multiples of 2^n where n can be positive or negative (i.e. 1.75 = 7 * 2^-2).

Comment: Yup, you are correct Mike, that's about the mathematical definition of "in finite places" in this case. 1.75 would be 2^0 + 2^-1 + 2^-2.

Comment: I'm actually surprised by the number of people that are surprised to see this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

javascript uses the `double` datatype, which can't, due to restricted binary places, express all decimal numbers accurately (not all numbers can be expressed with finite binary places). You can read more at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: Well, it looks like this question has been asked before. ;O) Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

You should read this:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

It's not a bug; it's just a well-known fact of floating point numbers for every language.

Answer (score 2):

In binary, this is the infinitely repeating binary fraction `11000101.10(10101110000101000111)` - which cannot be represented in a finite number of bits, so it is rounded to an approximation.